Cannot run Junit tests under Intellij but can under maven within Intellij IDE
Until recently I have been able to run Java Junit tests in Intellij, in maven  under Intellj and in maven standalone. However recently I can not run them in Intellij as I get the message:
Error: Could not find or load main class '--enable-preview'

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '--enable-preview'
I haven't found any issues in running them using the other methods. In maven surefire, I have the argument --enable-preview set.
I tried setting the --enable-preview setting in Intellij's standard Junit Template, but I still get the same message.
I am not sure what experimental features I am using that would need me to enable preview.
Update:
This is one of my Junit Intellij run congurations

JUnit Run Configuration Template
Update:
Before I delete my projects workspace and reload the source form GIT.
1.I tried reinstalling Intellij and using the same workspace.
2.I have tried running tests on another project using the reinstalled
Intellij and the same workspace and the tests ran to completion. I assume there must be something incorrectly set on the project parameters.
3.I did a visual search through the projects configuration files under the .idea directory searching for the string --enable-preview. I found three instances of the string in the workspace.xml file under JUnit with a VM-OPTIONS parameter that contained "-ea --enable-preview". I couldn't find the string anywhere else so I am at a loss to where the parameter is coming from. Unfortunately I didn't take a screen shot.
4.I deleted the projects workspace.xml file from my Intellij environment and ran one of the tests again with the same result. Here is a snippet from the workspace.xml file showing the jUnit parameters


 <component name="RunManager" selected="JUnit.JFXGoldenMeanImplTest">
  <configuration name="JFXGoldenMeanImplTest" type="JUnit" factoryName="JUnit" temporary="true" nameIsGenerated="true">
    <module name="PictureTool" />
    <extension name="coverage">
      <pattern>
        <option name="PATTERN" value="omac.picture.ui.drawpanel.*" />
        <option name="ENABLED" value="true" />
      </pattern>
    </extension>
    <option name="PACKAGE_NAME" value="omac.picture.ui.drawpanel" />
    <option name="MAIN_CLASS_NAME" value="omac.picture.ui.drawpanel.JFXGoldenMeanImplTest" />
    <option name="TEST_OBJECT" value="class" />
    <method v="2">
      <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
    </method>
    </configuration>
    <list>
      <item itemvalue="Application.JFXPictureToolMain" />
      <item itemvalue="JUnit.JFXGoldenMeanImplTest" />
      <item itemvalue="Maven.PictureTool4 [clean,install]" />
    </list>
    <recent_temporary>
      <list>
        <item itemvalue="JUnit.JFXGoldenMeanImplTest" />
      </list>
    </recent_temporary>
  </component>



There are no VM-OPTIONS listed here.

I have also tried using ChatGPT by giving it images of my Intellij junit testing configurations and it replied with

"-ea in VM Options: You also have -ea in the VM options, which stands for Enable Assertions. This is fine and useful for debugging, but ensure that you don't have unnecessary VM options causing interference. If you don't need it, you could try removing it, leaving only --enable-preview.
Working Directory: The working directory is set to $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$, which is the default and should work fine unless your tests need a different working directory.
Environment Variables: This field is empty, which is also fine since the --enable-preview flag doesn't belong here (it belongs in the VM options field as you've done)."
I have tried removing the -ea option with the same result.
The following are the java parameters used by Intellij to run the test:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin\java.exe" -ea --enable-preview "'--enable-preview'" -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=53815:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.8.2\junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.4\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\PictureTool4\target\test-classes;C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\PictureTool4\target\classes;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.17.2\log4j-core-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.25.3\assertj-core-3.25.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.11\byte-buddy-1.14.11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.8.1\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\3.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\2.0.0\jakarta.activation-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.3\jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.3\txw2-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.11\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\3.0.0\jaxb-impl-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\3.0.0\jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.28.0-GA\javassist-3.28.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\22\javafx-controls-22.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\22\javafx-controls-22-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\22\javafx-media-22-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\22\javafx-graphics-22.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\22\javafx-graphics-22-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\22\javafx-base-22.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\22\javafx-base-22-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\22\javafx-fxml-22.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\22\javafx-fxml-22-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\22\javafx-swing-22.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\22\javafx-swing-22-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.8.2\junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.8.2\junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.2\apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\5.12.0\mockito-core-5.12.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.15\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.15.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\3.3\objenesis-3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-junit-jupiter\5.12.0\mockito-junit-jupiter-5.12.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.8.2\junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.2.0\opentest4j-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.8.2\junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-params\5.8.2\junit-jupiter-params-5.8.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest\2.2\hamcrest-2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\2.2\hamcrest-library-2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\2.2\hamcrest-core-2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-csv\1.4\commons-csv-1.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\testfx\testfx-junit5\4.0.18\testfx-junit5-4.0.18.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\testfx\testfx-core\4.0.18\testfx-core-4.0.18.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\osgi\org.osgi.core\6.0.0\org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 omac.picture.ui.drawpanel.JFXGoldenMeanImplTest


please add your command to run junit test, I think you put argument --enable-preview in a wrong space.

I decided the best solution to this problem was to refresh the project workspace but this solution didn't get to the bottom of the issue why the tests were not running in Intellij.
The steps I took were:

Checked in my code changes into the project on GITHub.
Deleted the project from my workspace.
Restored the project workspace from the GITHub.
Checked out the project branch I was working on.

This has resolved the problem and Intellij tests now run.
